# Is it possible to define an specific size to lists in python dataclasses?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Similarly to what vec3d p[3] in c++ would make, that is, define a list of size 3 whose contents are of type vec3d.

Comment: No. I'm not sure what this has to do with dataclasses either. You could maybe use a tuple, instead, which can be annoted to have a specific size. Although note, `dataclasses.dataclass` doesn't enforce any of this

Comment: Why do you want to try to do that instead of using standard python list?

Comment: I think you can take a look at the queue instead. I don't think list is able to do that. https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Answer (score 1):

I think specifying the expected length of a list is not doable with a dataclass at the moment.
However you could use the `__post_init__` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) method to write some validation code:

> ```
> from dataclasses import dataclass
>
> @dataclass
> class ExampleDataclass:
>      some_variable: list[float]
>    
>      def __post_init__(self) -> None:
>          assert len(self.some_variable) == 3, f"some_variable expects a list with 3 elements!"
>
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     example_dataclass = ExampleDataclass(some_variable=[0, 1, 2])  # works
>     # example_dataclass = ExampleDataclass(some_variable=[0, 1])  # fails
>     # example_dataclass = ExampleDataclass(some_variable=[0, 1, 2, 3])  # fails as well
> ```